# Method destructuring not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to determine why this wont function properly.

```
// assuming this works
const { emitter } = window.project;
emitter.emit('foo');

// why doesnt this
const { emitter: { emit } } = window.project;
emit('foo');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably because the `emit` method depends on `this` referring to a specific value. The value of `this` depends on *how* a function is called (if it's an unbound, non-arrow function), and you are calling the function in two different ways:

- `emitter.emit()` will cause `this` inside `emit` to refer to `emitter`
- `emit()` will cause `this` to refer to `undefined` (strict mode) or the global object (non-strict mode)

That has nothing to do with ES6 specifically.

More information about `this`: [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/31e1d4ff600d88cc2ce243903ab8a3a9d15cce15/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes).

Comment: Sounds right. Is there any adaptation of the destructure shown above?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is something like `const { emitter } = window.project; const emit = emitter.emit.bind(emitter);`, which is just the usual binding. Or `let { emitter, emitter: { emit } } = window.project; emit = emit.bind(emitter);`, but that looks a bit weird to me. Of course if you have control over the code of the emitter, you can bind the `emit` method there, in which case your destructuring statement would work.

Comment: Its interesting that the destructure doesn’t maintain the biding relationships. Much appreciated!

Comment: Destructuring is really just syntactic sugar for property / array access, i.e. `var emit = window.property.emitter.emit;`.